# disable a inputfield on clicking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i want to disable an `input` field (`id = reg`) on clicking the `checkbox`. I want to use jquery, but I did it with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
<head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <title>FIMS</title>   
    <meta name="description" content="Sales tracking system">   
    <title>FIMS::Data analyst</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/my_style_sheet/my_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/my_style_sheet/mys_style_sheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/my_js/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/my_js/js_library.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#all').change(function(){
            $('#reg').attr("disabled","disabled");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Choose District</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="bootstrap-select" name="district" id="dis" disabled='disabled'></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Regionwise</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post html also

Comment: Does js_library.js include jquery?

Comment: yap it includes @Huangism

Comment: Where is you `#reg` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#all').change(function () {
        $('#reg').prop("disabled", this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MwX2/)

Comment: What is the version of jQuery file you are using? Is the fiddle demo working for you?

Comment: Fiddle is working for me. On clicking the checkbox is the input box below not getting disabled and vice-versa?

Comment: Ok, so what is the version of jQuery file you are using?

Comment: JavaScript Library v1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

It is Simple

Try :

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){

    $("#sample").attr("disabled","true");
});
```

Here is Jsfiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/88px7/1/

Answer (score 0):

what is id of checkbox ?

your code looks right but please check http://api.jquery.com/change/

check without $(document).ready()
also check your jquery reference

Comment: in your html there is not id reg

Comment: i meant dis, reg was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#all').toggle(function() {
        if($('#all').attr('checked')) {
            $('#reg').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#reg').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

You may also use the `click()` event of the checkbox.

> Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.